# Grab list of site collections from SPFarm object

Tags: 2010, development, spcontext

I have a Farm level feature that returns null when I try to access `SPContect.Current.Site`. Is another way to grab a list of site collections? I have access to `SPFarm.Local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jevgeni/archive/2009/12/27/iterating-through-all-web-applications-in-a-sharepoint-farm.aspx)... You need to get the web applications first then iterate through each web application's sites.

Can't this be a web applicatiion feature? Why exactly would you make it a farm feature?

Comment: I'm uploading InfoPath forms. I guess maybe it could be a Web Application feature, I haven't tried yet.